# Elastic Search: filter search results based on values in aray of objects in elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have an array of objects with mapping:

```
"mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "something" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "key1" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "key2" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
```

I have an input like -[{key1: "x",key2:"y"},{key1:"x",key2:"z"}].

How can I filter the results that contain this exact set of combinations of key1 and key2

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```
PUT test_your_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "something": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key1": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "key2": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST test_your_index/_bulk?refresh
{ "index" : { "_id" : "1" } }
{ "something" : [{ "key1" : "x", "key2" : "y" }, { "key1" : "x", "key2" : "z" }] }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "2" } }
{ "something" : [{ "key1" : "x", "key2" : "y" }, { "key1" : "a", "key2" : "b" }] }
{ "index" : { "_id" : "3" } }
{ "something" : [{ "key1" : "x", "key2" : "z" }, { "key1" : "z", "key2" : "w" }] }
```

---

```
POST test_your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "something",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "something.key1": "x" }},
            { "match": { "something.key2": "y" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```